# ¿Cómo publicar archivo php guardado en Administrador de archivos (File Manager) de cPanel que acceda a base de datos MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, c#, visual-studio, cpanel

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Windows Forms en Visual Studio C# que se conecta a una base de datos MySQL en un servidor remoto con herramientas de cPanel. Mi jefe ahora pretende venderla y por lo tanto necesito 2 cosas:

1. Que el programa compruebe licencia cuando el cliente la introduzca
2. Que a partir de la licencia descargue la cadena de conexión de ese cliente (para acceder a su base de datos)

Se me ocurre que podría hacer una base de datos que guarde la cadena de conexión del cliente y que solamente la descargue si se registró una licencia válida pero que limite el número de intentos para consultar licencia (para evitar que un programa se ponga a intentar strings al azar para encontrar la licencia).

Entonces se me ocurrió que podría poner un archivo php que solicite el ip (para limitar el número de intentos) de quién solicita y su licencia, que acceda a la base de datos de licencias y en caso de que la licencia exista que regrese la cadena de conexión correspondiente.

Para acceder al archivo php se me ocurrió utilizar la clase WebRequest desde la aplicación Windows Forms en C#.

Seguí el siguiente tutorial para publicar un archivo php:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7fZIxJzhKc

El problema es que cuando intento acceder al archivo php a partir del url "dominio.com/test.php" me aparece el error 404, intente dando todos los permisos a ese archivo pero aún asi no puedo acceder.

No estoy cerrado a ninguna opción alternativa, necesito resolver los 2 problemas mencionados arriba.

Agradezco especialmente notas referentes a la seguridad del sistema, (por cierto tengo un par de rutinas para encriptar y desencriptar la cadena de conexión, pero quizá no es suficiente porque alguien podría vigilar la RAM de la pc para obtener la cadena de conexión y/o la licencia cuando el programa desencripte esa información).

Doy gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan.

Comment: Creo que te estas complicando mucho ¿Leer la RAM? ¿pero quien va a hacer eso?, ese tipo de crack se hacen a office, Photosho o a juegos, a ese nivel de aplicaciones, con todo el respeto del mundo no creo que nadie se de el trabajo para tu caso. Lo más simple es desactivar la base de datos si alguien no paga

Comment: ¿Si ubicas que es espionaje industrial? no solamente pasa, ya le pasó a mi jefe que accedieron a su información, la encriptaron y le exigieron dinero para recuperarla (no pagó pero le ocasionó muchos problemas), es verdad que ya no la perdería porque puse un mecanismo de respaldo de base de datos una vez por semana, pero en la base de datos hay información de clientes y procedimientos que no quieren que otros obtengan.

Comment: Llevo bastantes años desarrollando y vendiendo software, por eso te digo que el mejor sistema para evitar no pagos del servicio es desactivar la DB, obviamente cuando la DB está en tus servidores, como es tu caso.